ScrollView used in side Grid control in complex ui gives extra space in Android
 <Grid
    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
    RowDefinitions="Auto, *, Auto"
    VerticalOptions="Fill">
    <customControls:InspectionHeaderView Title="{Binding Path=Title}" Grid.Row="0" />

    <ScrollView
        x:Name="scrollView"
        Grid.Row="1"
        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, *, *">
            <VerticalStackLayout
                x:Name="container"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Padding="20,15">
                <!--Other controls-->
            </VerticalStackLayout>

            <CollectionView
                Grid.Row="2"
                ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedViolationItem.InspectionHealthViolationCodeRefs}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="inspections:InspectionHealthViolationCodeRef">
                        <!--Other controls-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>

            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="3" VerticalOptions="Start">
                <!--CollectionView inside this-->

            </VerticalStackLayout>
            
        </Grid>

    </ScrollView>

    <Grid
        Grid.Row="2"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource WhiteSmoke}"
        ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*"
        VerticalOptions="End">
    </Grid>

</Grid>

Check the attached screenshot

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? In iOS it works fine.

Why is your CollectionView in a ScrollView...

I have multiple lists in the Page and other controls too outside these Collections, so I have wrap it all in ScrollView. Its complex ui.

CollectionView and ScrollView are not meant to be used together, you use them together you will see such UI issues

What the view looks like on the iOS device? Have you tried adding the HeightRequest to the controls to fill the extra space?

Yes,  in iOS it works fine. I have used MaximumHeightRequest property to handle this ui issue.

Can you provide the screenshot of the view on iOS?

What effect do you want to achieve? Regardless of whether there are attachments in the CollectionView, the "Add Attachments" button should appear at the bottom of the page, right?

No, when there is no attachment and showing this empty view its showing extra space at bottom in Android that should not happen. To fix that I have to use MaximumHeightRequest property.
